# Python coding for SQLite is not populating the Database

Tags: python, sqlite, imdb

I found a tutorial online that will let a user input a movie in the command line and it will search IMDB and return all the information. That is working.

So I decided I wanted to be able to import the movie data into a SQLite database. The database is being generated with the table but is not getting the information and I am not getting an error. Here is what I have.

Here is the SQLite code:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
def sql_connection():
    try:
        con=sqlite3.connect('movies.db')
        return con
    except Error:
        print(Error)

def sql_table(con):
    cursorObj=con.cursor()
    cursorObj.execute("CREATE TABLE movies(id integer PRIMARY KEY,\ 
    tite text, year integer, full cast text, rating integer, plot \
    text )")

    con.commit()
con=sql_connection()
sql_table(con)

def sql_insert(con,entities):
    cursorObj=con.cursor()
    cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO movies(id, title, year of \
    release, full cast, rating, cast) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',entities)\
    con.commit()
sql_insert(con,entities)
con.close()
```

Comment: What is `entities` in `sql_insert(con,entities)`? Are you getting any errors? Please read [ask].

Comment: Not sure on the entities. I was following a tutorial. I am not getting any errors though,.

Answer (score 0):

I see mistakes:

Typo: `tite` instead of `title` in:

```
cursorObj.execute("CREATE TABLE movies(id integer PRIMARY KEY,\ 
tite text, year integer, full cast text, rating integer, plot \
text )")
```

In the second statement, you are attempting to update field `year of release`, that doesn't exist (you named it `year` earlier).

```
cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO movies(id, title, year of \
release, full cast, rating, cast) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',entities)\
con.commit()
```

If you are going to use column names containing spaces, you'll need back ticks or square brackets, something that I would avoid. So instead of `full cast` I would use the underscore character (`_`) to avoid spaces: `full_cast`. But in your `create` statement you called the field `cast` so the insert is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I made the corrections that you suggested. I fixed the misspellings, I used under scores for the names and called cast, full cast. I also noticed on the insert I had two cast. I changed the last cast to plot, whic is what it was suppose to be. But I am still getting an empty database. It makes the table and that is it. Thank you for your hellp.